# Wrap section and main body into one form in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 project I have a master layout with a section defined. This section is responsible for displaying content in a sidebar, when it has any content assigned to it.

The problem I've encountered is the following:

I have some edit views, where both the sidebar and the main area is used for editing data. In this case the sidebar and the main body should be wrapped into one single form with a single submit button.

What is the best solution for this? The solution I came up with is that when the functionality I mentioned is necessary, I set a boolean property in my ViewBag. If this property is true, the master layout is rendered with the sidebar and the main content area wrapped in a form.

Is there a better way to this? The solution I described is a bit 'hackish' for me.

Comment: You sure you can't use separate forms for the sidebar/main area?  Seems odd to me that they would be separated into different views and yet related as far as posting the data.

Comment: Suppose that you are editing an article. The sidebar displays some general data (title, category etc) and the main content area has a wysiwyg editor. This scenario is pretty common for various objects in my app, and the predefined section makes it simpler & faster to build these UIs. Do you have better idea to this?

Comment: I'd probably have separate actions for updating metadata and content and use separate forms.

Comment: For now I don't use AJAX, so it could be confusing when you update meta, and lose the edits in the editor.

Comment: Is it possible to just put the details in the sidebar and the editing portion in the main area with the rest? Just seems like either the section is a separate entity and should work independently.

Comment: The edit screen used to edit a single entity, not two related entities. Here is a screenshot about the ui, to make it easier to understand the scenario -> http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/3157/screenyrv.png

Comment: I see what you mean.  You might want to consider two different layouts and switch layouts when you need the sidebar wrapped in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have two layouts.  One with a seperate side-bar, and one without.  Then, in the pages you need a sidebar with editable fields, you include the sidebar in your content page, not in the master.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean you are using in the ViewBag can be better represented in the Model for the view of the master page. You can then include the side bar using a partial view. It would look somehting like this...

master.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", "POST")){
        //
        // Master form elements go here
        //

    //Side bar
   @if(Model.ShowSideBar){
     @Html.Partial("MySideBarPartialView" [, Model.SideBarModel ] )

   @}
@}
```

You model (if any) should have a property that is set with the model for the side bar.